# Can a GPU slow down an entire system and share data/memory with RAM

Tags: windows-7, memory, graphics-card, performance

I have been having problems recently where bars are changing colour on screen.

I believe it is my graphics card dying. However, after experiencing some lag on my computer I decided to wipe it, after reinstalling everything it should work fine, however, it seems like the RAM is doing 4 times as much as it is supposed to sometimes now. Yesterday i had no windows open, no other processes like Steam or Discord being used and i was using like 7.4GB out of 8GB of RAM.

Will the computer run faster if I upgrade my GPU, or should something else be prioritised?

System specs:

- Geforce Gtx 650
- Intel i5 3470 @3.2GHz
- 8GB DDR3 RAM
- Windows 7 64-bit Home premium (I am aware that this is no longer being supported by Microsoft now).

Comment: I don't know why you think Windows 7 is no longer supported. It still is. They dropped support for Vista.

Comment: Nvidia has Windows 7 drivers for your card. As long as that is the case, it doesn't matter if Microsoft supports Windows 7 (they do), because Microsoft doesn't publish the device drivers for your card.  The performance of your computer's CPU will not be effected by which GPU you have installed.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is no. Maybe you could identify what process is eating your memory and post it here so we can figure out what is going on your computer.
Do you have installed something new ? Did you update drivers etc.
Beside windows 7 no longer supported by Microsoft (even if this statement is false) doesn't mean your computer will suddenly going crazy and stop working. It means that there will be no more features added but only security update.